# Angularで重いタブへの移動時にLoadingを差し込みたい

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular Materialのtabを使用して、多くのFormをもつタブを作成しました。
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-aanv2p?)

この重いタブへの移動時に時間がかかることから、Loading中である旨のダイアログを出したいとおもったのですが、
以下のように`mat-tab-group`のクリックイベントでは、ダイアログが表示される前に画面がフリーズしてしまい、
タブの移動後にダイアログが出るようになってしまします。

```
<md-tab-group (click)="openDialog()">
  <md-tab label="light-page1">
    <app-light-page></app-light-page>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="heavy-page">
    <app-heavy-page></app-heavy-page>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="light-page2">
    <app-light-page></app-light-page>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

重いタブへの移動時にLoadingを表示した状態で画面がフリーズするようにはできませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一度に表示する量を制御したほうがいいです

フォークして修正したものです
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-p6xtfm?file=app%2Fheavy-page%2Fheavy-page.component.ts

1度に1万のinputをレンダリングするのはとても重いのでintervalで小分けに表示するようにしました

```js
const interval = setInterval(() => {
      for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        this.hformGroups.push(
          this.fb.group({
            val: [index * 100 + i]
          })
        );
      }
      index++;
      if (index > 100) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 300);
```

**追記**
`md-tab-group` は最初にタブページを開いた時点でlight-page1、heavy-page, ight-page2のレンダリングを開始します。これは各タブページのngInitにログを出力すると振る舞いがわかると思います

このため単にローディング表示をしたいだけなら、タブクリックのタイミングでngIfを使いタブページを表示するような制御をしてもうまくいくと思います

Comment: 根本的な解決策をありがとうございました！提案いただいた内容を参考にして、今回は一度すべてのフォームを作成してvalidationも行いたかったので、<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>を使用して対応しました。